Are big square roots allowed on the title?
This question appears on my page like this :
I thought the problem was because the length of the equations under the \sqrt, I got sick of it so decided to edited to fix it and it became like this: 
It seems that $\sum$ under $\sqrt{}$ will cause this problem to happen, but this doesn't explain the problem in the title before my edit, It seems that my first guess is correct that the length of the equations under the \sqrt willk cause this problem but this raises the following question What is the max length allowed under \sqrt before it causes a problem in  the title.

It does not seem to cause any problems for me.

@Lucenaposition what device do you use ?

I use a computer with Google Chrome browser.

@Lucenaposition that is weird, am I the only one who have this issue ?

@pie  I don't see where you specify your browser and device combination.  Also you should share the MathJax renderer (from the "right click" menu on formulas).  In general sparing use of MathJax in titles is recommended.

@hardmath I use a pc and chrome.

I think there were some similar reports from the past - for example this one:
Multiline MathJax on title.
Although it is marked as ([meta-tag:status-completed]).

Please refer to Guidelines for good use of MathJax in question titles.  Your title does not seem to follow those guidelines.
In particular: Avoid complex MathJax that takes up a lot of vertical space.  Your title seems to violate this.  (For instance, it exceeds the "approximate upper bound for what is admissible" -- see that page to understand what I am referring to.)
Use words.  This is important for search to work well.  It also helps make the title accessible to those with visual impairments (e.g., those using screen readers).  Your title contains only the word "Show" and no other words.
I suggest reviewing those guidelines, then improving the title.

I would suggest the title, "Inequality involving sum of square roots of sum of squares".
